# Getting HTTP status code 415: Unsupported Media type exception for Get API using Rest Template

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

I have created two spring boot projects called MS1 and MS2 running on different ports in my local system. MS1.controller has /GetAPI which call the external API end point which is MS2.controller /GetAPI. When I run MS2 it fetches the data in JSON. But when I trigger the API with MS1 then it throws 415 Unsupported Media Type. In spring boot by default data format is JSON. I have even created the headers and added to the restTemplate.getForObject() method. Please refer my code and let me know where it is going wrong.

### MS1

main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("ondc_account_validation")
public class OndcAccountValidation {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SpringApplication.run(OndcAccountValidation.class, args);

    }
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SubscriberAccount getSubscriberAccount() {
        return new SubscriberAccount();
    }

}
```

Domain :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "subscriber_id",
    "unique_key_id",
    "participant_legal_name",
    "participant_type",
    "pan",
    "bank_details",
    "created_at",
    "updated_at"
})

public class SubscriberAccount {

    @JsonProperty("subscriber_id")
    private String subscriber_id;

    @JsonProperty("unique_key_id")
    private String unique_key_id;

    @JsonProperty("participant_legal_name")
    private String participant_legal_name;

    @JsonProperty("participant_type")
    private String participant_type;

    @JsonProperty("pan")
    private PanDetails panDetails;

    @JsonProperty("bank_details")
    private BankAccountDetails accountDetails;

    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    private String created_at;

    @JsonProperty("updated_at")
    private String updated_at;
    private List<SubscriberAccount> subsAccount;
    
    /**/
    public String getSubscriber_id() {
        return subscriber_id;
    }

    public void setSubscriber_id(String subscriber_id) {
        this.subscriber_id = subscriber_id;
    }

    public String getUnique_key_id() {
        return unique_key_id;
    }

    public void setUnique_key_id(String unique_key_id) {
        this.unique_key_id = unique_key_id;
    }

    public String getParticipant_legal_name() {
        return participant_legal_name;
    }

    public void setParticipant_legal_name(String participant_legal_name) {
        this.participant_legal_name = participant_legal_name;
    }

    public String getParticipant_type() {
        return participant_type;
    }

    public void setParticipant_type(String participant_type) {
        this.participant_type = participant_type;
    }

    public PanDetails getPanDetails() {
        return panDetails;
    }

    public void setPanDetails(PanDetails panDetails) {
        this.panDetails = panDetails;
    }

    public BankAccountDetails getAccountDetails() {
        return accountDetails;
    }

    public void setAccountDetails(BankAccountDetails accountDetails) {
        this.accountDetails = accountDetails;
    }

    public String getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public String getUpdated_at() {
        return updated_at;
    }

    public void setUpdated_at(String updated_at) {
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    public SubscriberAccount(String subscriber_id, String unique_key_id, String participant_legal_name,
            String participant_type, PanDetails panDetails, BankAccountDetails accountDetails, String created_at,
            String updated_at) {
        super();
        this.subscriber_id = subscriber_id;
        this.unique_key_id = unique_key_id;
        this.participant_legal_name = participant_legal_name;
        this.participant_type = participant_type;
        this.panDetails = panDetails;
        this.accountDetails = accountDetails;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    public SubscriberAccount() {
        
    }
    public List<SubscriberAccount> getSubsAccount() {
        return subsAccount;
    }
    public void setSubsAccount(List<SubscriberAccount> subsAccount) {
        this.subsAccount = subsAccount;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class AccountValidationController {
    @Autowired
    FetchRegistrationDetails fetchRegistrationDetailsSerivce;
    
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @RequestMapping(value ="/registration", consumes ="application/json" , produces="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<SubscriberAccount>> getRegistrationDetails() throws URISyntaxException {
        
        List<SubscriberAccount> subAccountList  = fetchRegistrationDetailsSerivce.fetchRegistrationDetails();
        
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(subAccountList);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface FetchRegistrationDetails {
    
    public List<SubscriberAccount> fetchRegistrationDetails() throws URISyntaxException;
}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Service("fetchRegistrationDetails")
public class FetchRegistrationDetailsImpl implements FetchRegistrationDetails {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    SendToExcel sendToExcel;

    public List<SubscriberAccount> fetchRegistrationDetails() throws URISyntaxException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = "http://localhost:8091/api/registrationAPI";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        
        List<SubscriberAccount> subAccList = (List<SubscriberAccount>) restTemplate.getForObject(url,
                List.class, headers);
        // List<SubscriberAccount> subcrLi st = subAccList.getBody();

        for (SubscriberAccount subscriberAccount : subAccList) {
            System.out.println(subscriberAccount);
        }

        sendToExcel.saveDataToExcel(subAccList);

        return subAccList;
    }

}
```

### MS2:

Domain:
Same domain as above

Controller:
@RestController

```
public class SimulatorController {
    
    static final String url = "http:localhost:8091/api/registrationAPI";
    @Autowired
    private  SimulatorService simulatorService;
    
    
    @GetMapping(value ="/registrationAPI", consumes ="application/json" , produces="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<SimulatorDTO>> sendRegistrationData() throws Exception {
        List<SimulatorDTO> simulatorEntity = simulatorService.sendRegistrationData();
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        
        
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).headers(headers).body(simulatorEntity);
    }
}
```

serviceInterface:

```
@Component
public interface SimulatorService {

    

    public List<SimulatorDTO> sendRegistrationData() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException;

    List<SimulatorDTO> fetchDetailsFromExcel(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException;
}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class SimulatorServiceImpl implements SimulatorService {

    @Override
    public List<SimulatorDTO> sendRegistrationData() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        File file = new File("D:\\Workspace\\RegistrationData.xlsx");
        
        
          List<SimulatorDTO> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
PanDTO panDTO = new PanDTO("AVLPT1847Q", "DummyName", "12-12-2011");
          
          BankDTO bankDTO = new BankDTO("202120211077", "SBIN000836", "DummyName",
          "Nodal"); 
          list.add(new SimulatorDTO("ABC.com", "123456789ABC", "DUmmyName",
          panDTO, bankDTO, "2023-01-23", "2023-01-23")); 
          list.add(new SimulatorDTO("AcC.com", "1233356789ABC", "DuummyName", panDTO, bankDTO,
          "2023-01-24", "2023-01-24"));
         
        
        System.out.print(list);
        return list;
    }
```

Please let me know what are your thoughts.
Note: I am not using any DB here I am just saving in excel.

I tried manually setting the headers with Content-Type is Application/json. but no use still it says 415 error code.

I am expecting a new approach and mostly used approach if avoids these kind of bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using `restTemplate.getForObject`, it's not accepting headers as a 3rd param but `uriVariables`

See more details in [the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-)

```
url - the URL
responseType - the type of the return value
uriVariables - the variables to expand the template
```

Please try to use `restTemplate.exchange` instead and pass requestEntity as a 3rd param. You could create them from headers like that

```
HttpEntity<Void> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
```

So you should have something like that

```
 restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, List.class);
```

Comment: Hi @fedden, thanks for responding. Url will be fetching some array of SubscriberAccount objects and I am  using List<SubscriberAccount>. But it has to convert to the list of objects right. I am getting that error. Or I have to cast to List<SubscriberAccount>. Anyway when I call, I am getting some other exception. Mismatched input exception.

Comment: Please share the full exception message 

Comment: Hi fedden, I have used  restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<SubscriberAccount>>() {
    });. Now the issue has been resolved

Comment: Awesome, if you feel like my responses helped to you please approve my answer 